# Get Count of records - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get count of records from table by joining 2 or more table. Suppose I have 3 table like follows,

```
Table A
Column 1   Column 2
121        XX
123        XX
124        A0
125        A2
126        XX

Table B
Column 1
A0
A1
A2
A3

Table C
Column 1 Column 2
121        A0
122        A1
123        A0
124        A0
125        A2
126        A3
```

From these I need count result as follows,

```
Column 1     Column 2
XX,A0        2
XX,A1        0        
XX,A2        0
XX,A3        1
A0,A0        1
A1,A1        0
A2,A2        1
A3,A3        0
```

Here I have 121 and 123 with XX in table A and same 121,123 in table C with A0, so count should be 2. Similarly 124 have A0 in table A and A0 in table C, so count should 1 and if no record matched with any column 2 it should have 0.

I tried with below query it is not returing as expected,

```
select b.column2 ||','|| c.column2 column , count(a.column1) count
          from table A a
          join table c c
           on a.column1=c.column1       
          join table b b
            on b.column1=c.column2
        group by b.column2 ||','|| c.column2
        order by b.column2 ||','|| c.column2
```

Answer (score 0):

`Table A` should be used instead of `Table B` for combining the values. Table B doesn't have column `Colunn2`.

Also, Remember alias name for `a.column2 ||','|| c.column2` should not be `column` as this is reserved keyword in oracle. So you can use `column2` or something else.

**EDIT: Following will give `0` count for not matched records.**

```
select t1.column2,
case when t2.count1 is not null then t2.count1 else t1.count1 end as count1 
from (
(select distinct a.column2||','||b.column1 as column2,
 0 as count1 from tableA a join tableB b on  a.column2='XX'
union 
select distinct c.column2||','||b.column1 as column2,
 0 as count1 from tableC c join tableB b on c.column2=b.column1
)t1
left join 
(select a.Column2 ||','|| c.Column2 as column2, 
  count(*) count1 from TableA a join TableC c on a.column1=c.column1 
  join TableB B on b.column1=c.column2 group by a.column2 ||','|| c.column2 
)t2
on t1.column2=t2.column2
)
order by 
t1.column2
```

Output:

```
A0,A0   1
A1,A1   0
A2,A2   1
A3,A3   0
XX,A0   2
XX,A1   0
XX,A2   0
XX,A3   1
```

Answer (score 0):

first you would want a cartesian product to get the set of all possible combinations betweeen tablea and tableb. I changed the column names to something more readable.

```
create table tablea(id int, name varchar2(10));

create table tableb(name varchar2(10));

create table tablec(id int, name varchar2(10));

insert into tablea
select 121,'XX' from dual union all
select 123,'XX' from dual union all
select 124,'A0' from dual union all
select 125,'A2' from dual union all
select 126,'XX' from dual 

insert into tableb
select 'A0' from dual union all
select 'A1' from dual union all
select 'A2' from dual union all
select 'A3' from dual 

insert into tablec
select 121,'A0' from dual union all
select 122,'A1' from dual union all
select 123,'A0' from dual union all
select 124,'A0' from dual union all
select 125,'A2' from dual union all 
select 126,'A3' from dual 

--Gets all possible combination of tablea and tableb
select distinct a.name as a_name,b.name as b_name
       from tablea a
       join tableb b
         on 1=1
```

Then you would do a group by on these combination fields as follows

```
with data
 as (select distinct a.name as a_name,b.name as b_name
       from tablea a
       join tableb b
         on 1=1
     )  
    ,tablec_data
     as (select c.name c_name,a.name a_name
           from tablec c
           join tablea a
             on c.id=a.id
       )
select max(m.a_name||','||m.b_name) as val_name,count(n.c_name) as cnt
  from data m
left join tablec_data n
    on m.a_name=n.a_name
    and m.b_name=n.c_name
group by m.a_name,m.b_name    
order by m.a_name desc,m.b_name
```

Here is a db fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e573822ecc1087e5871c80b586d1116

```
+----------+-----+
| VAL_NAME | CNT |
+----------+-----+
| XX,A0    |   2 |
| XX,A1    |   0 |
| XX,A2    |   0 |
| XX,A3    |   1 |
| A2,A0    |   0 |
| A2,A1    |   0 |
| A2,A2    |   1 |
| A2,A3    |   0 |
| A0,A0    |   1 |
| A0,A1    |   0 |
| A0,A2    |   0 |
| A0,A3    |   0 |
+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

At first prepare key columns, use simple union. Then use this `keys` to construct join. `Left join` is used because we need zeros too:

```
with keys as (select 'XX' ka, column1 kb from b union all select column1, column1 from b)
select ka, kb, sum(case when c.column2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) cnt
  from keys
  left join a on ka = a.column2
  left join c on kb = c.column2 and a.column1 = c.column1
  group by ka, kb
  order by ka, kb
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fa651dc7166b5879cc0d025034d41612)</sup>**